Modifying numpy array with `numpy.take`-like function
I know that in numpy, I can use numpy.take to get the subarray at a particular axis value instead of using fancy indexing.
So, if I have a 2D array a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), then I can write a[0, :] or np.take(a, 0, axis=0) to get the same result.
However, the two are not equivalent in the sense that I can use the first one to also set values, while I cannot do the same with the second. In other words, I can do this:
a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
a[0, :] = 10
# I now expect and also get:
# a = [[10, 10],
#      [3,  4]

while I cannot do this:
a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
np.take(a, 0, axis=0) = 10
# returns an error: SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?

So, is there a numpy.take-like function that will allow me to set values, without doing fancy indexing? The motivation here is that I want the axis upon which I am changing values to be settable by the user, so I can't just do a[0, :] because I might need to do a[:, 0]. Now of course I can use an if statement for this, but I am wondering if there is something simpler.

Note that there's another important difference between a[0, :] and how you're using numpy.take. numpy.take copies data, while a[0, :] produces a view. (numpy.take is supposed to be equivalent to "fancy", or "advanced" indexing, while a[0, :] is a "basic" indexing operation.)

@user2357112 Indeed, and in this case I would actually prefer it to return a view :)

Since a[:, 0] is equivalent to a[(slice(None), 0)], you can write a[(slice(None),) * axis + (indexes,)]. Alternatively, you could also use np.put_along_axis, but it's not clear whether this would be simpler than the former approach, or even the if statement approach.

Any way, np.take(a,0,axis=0)=10 wouldn't make any sense whatever np.take could be. That's not a np.take problem. That is a python problem. If np.take was doing exactly the same thing as a[:,0], it would still make no sense to np.take(...)=10. Or, said otherwise, if you define f: def f(a): return a[:,0], it still makes no sense to f(a)=10.

But, since what f (or your np.take call) returns is an array, what you are really trying to do is f(a)[:]=10. And that works as intended. (for a[:,0] you don't need to add a [:], since it is already there)

Now, indeed, np.take(a,0, axis=0)[:]=10, while not raising any error, still doen't work (doesn't modify a content. It does modify the result of np.take content, but that is lost). Because, of the real difference between np.take(a,0,axis=0) and a[:,0] pointed out by @user2357112 : it is a copy. So, even if you tried a code that makes sense (like np.take(a,0, axis=0)[:]=10, you would have changed only the content of a copy.

The corollary of numpy.take for setting elements is numpy.put, but unfortunately np.put does not take an axis argument. numpy.put_along_axis exists, but this has the indexing semantics of np.take_along_axis, which is different than what you asked.
I suspect the easiest way to achieve what you have in mind is to use np.take to generate indices that can then be passed to np.put. For example:
>>> a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> i = np.take(np.arange(a.size).reshape(a.shape), 0, axis=0)
>>> np.put(a, i, 10)
>>> print(a)
[[10 10]
 [ 3  4]]

Another possibility would be to combine numpy.apply_along_axis with np.put. For example:
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> np.apply_along_axis(np.put, arr=a, axis=0, ind=0, v=10)
>>> print(a)
[[10 10]
 [ 3  4]]

Though please be aware that apply_along_axis is implemented via loops rather than vectorized operations, so it may have poor performance for larger arrays.

Yes, I also found put in the documentation, but despite the inviting name, it is not directly the pair of take...

I don't like apply_along_axis.  It iterates on all dimensions except the named one, passing a 1d array to your function many times.  It's 'cute', but not fast.

Thanks - updated the answer to mention the potential performance impacts of apply_along_axis.

put_along_axis was mentioned.  Looking at its [source], the key step is
arr[_make_along_axis_idx(arr_shape, indices, axis)] = values

_make_along_axis_index is more involved ,but a key comment is
# build a fancy index, consisting of orthogonal aranges, with the
# requested index inserted at the right location

Those are similar to the broadcastable indexing arrays produced by np.ix_.  You can also make an indexing tuple like (0, slice(None)).

import numpy as np

# Create a 2D NumPy array
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print("Original array:")
print(a)

# Modify the array using np.put
# np.put(array, indices, values) replaces elements at specified indices with given values
# Create indices for all columns (0, 1)
indices = np.arange(a.shape[1])  
# Values to replace with (100 for all columns)
new_values = 100                 
np.put(a, indices, new_values)
print("Array after modification:")
print(a)

'''
Output:

Original array:
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]

Array after modification:
[[100 100]
 [  3   4]]
'''

